# $R_S (=K \cap A_{K,S})$ is a Dedekind domain

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, commutative-algebra, algebraic-number-theory, adeles

Let $K$ be a global field and let $S$ be a finite, nonempty set of places of $K$
containing the infinite one. Show that $R_S (=K \cap A_{K,S})$, the ring of $S$-integers of $K$, is a Dedekind domain. (Here  $A_{K,S}$ is the ring of $S$-adeles.)

Comment: @user26857 I have solved it